# Rerendering OutputLink with block elements inside of it

Tags: rerender, page-layout, outputlink

Whenever I try to rerender an outputpanel with an outputlink inside of it that has a `<div>` ( or other block elements ) inside of it, the `<a>` gets closed on rerender.

Instead of

```
<a href="#">
    <div>hi</div>
</a>`
```

I get:

```
<a href="#"></a>
<div>hi</div>
```

I validated all of the surrounding HTML and all of the HTML seems okay.

**Any tips on how to fix this?** Changing the display layout of the elements inside the link works, of course, but doesn't really solve the problem.

Edit -  here is my actual code:

```
<apex:outputLink value="#">
    <div class="icon">
        <i class="fa fa-icon"></i>
    </div>
    <h4>Header</h4>
    <p class="description">this is a description</p>
</apex:outputLink>
```

Making the `<div>` a `<span>` helps, and making the `<p>` an `outputPanel` helps, but I can't figure out the `<h4>`.  ( making these changes is NOT ideal ).

Comment: At least with HTML4, a div inside an anchor isn't valid.  I would agree with Eric, try using a span and display it as a block.
Have you tried using the outputLink and outputPanel tags, and changing the outputPanel's layout to block?

Comment: @ThomasCrouse I have done few things: wrapping everything in an output panel creates like 3 or 4 extra `<a>` tags (lol).  I've actually been able to get everything but the `<h4>` to work when `display:inline`.  No matter what I do, I can't get the h4 to stop the page from breaking.  Even when display inline.  Is there an apex tag that translates to an h#?

Comment: apex:sectionHeader translates to header tag(s), but that's probably not what you're looking for.  I've encountered issues as well trying to conditionally render headers and ended up just styling apex:outputText instead.
Do you have a more complete sample of your page to share?  <h4> isn't included in your current sample.

Comment: @ThomasCrouse my actual code was added!

Comment: I still think this is an issue of rerendering invalid html.  Any time I include a non-inline element in the anchor, the rerender behaves as you describe.
I found this related post about rerendering table rows and cells wrapped by inline outputPanels. http://ninjahate.blogspot.com/2011/08/salesforcecom-visualforce-rerender-pain.html
So, evaluate whether you really need your anchor to surround all those elements.  Maybe replace the anchor with a div and an onclick event. Otherwise, try updating your anchor with javascript during the oncomplete event of whatever triggers the rerender.  Good luck.

Comment: I actually had the same problem with tables and we spent 8 hours trying to find a fix.  We had a div onclick as a temp solution.  I checked my HTML against W3 and it's perfectly valid, so who knows.  Thanks for your help :)

Comment: Salesforce wraps <a> tags around divs all over the place. It's a thing, and VF should allow it, but definitely does not.

Answer (score 1):

Do you have to have a `<DIV>`?

If not, `<span>` works as expected

Comment: maybe if I give them `display:inline-block`.  If it fixes the problem, cool, but the rerender definitely shouldn't be dependant on the element types in between.

Answer (score 0):

Run into the same problem. Solved it with converting all the items inside  to  and writing display:block for this items in .css file.